# Minimal Ubuntu Elementary OS Port

Tags: elementary, pantheon

Can anyone help in creating a Ubuntu with the following packages.
Desktop Environment :Pantheon
GTK Theme :eGTK
Icon Theme :Moka Icon Theme
Terminal :Pantheon-Terminal
Settings :Switchboard
File Manager: Marlin/Pantheon-Files

Or
In short the same apps are available in Elementary OS Luna but the base is Ubuntu 12.04 which is very old. Can anyone port Elementary OS Luna to Ubuntu 13.10 or Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: -1 stating 12.04 is old OS is quite strange. 12.04 is an LTS so more stable than 13.10 or 14.04 (14.04 will become next LTS but at moment is in development and  can't be considered stable), probably your best shoot is going on with Elementary OS which is built on 12.04 for purpose (stability).

Comment: You can [install the themes icons from elementary-os](http://itsfoss.com/install-themes-icons-elementary-os-freya/)

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone port Elementary OS Luna to Ubuntu 13.10 or Ubuntu 14.04"

No, Elementary OS will never be ported to Ubuntu. Elementary OS is an OS in itself where someone took Ubuntu 12.04 and changed the code base and then published it as on OS named Elementary.

Your question probably should be: can someone create a new version of Elementary OS based of of Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10. On *elementaryos.org* there was a topic about this with this as an answer (no idea how official this is):

> Will we see an intermediate release based on 13.10?
>
> Since for the time being devs have to develop Isis of off 13.10 while waiting for 14.04 to mature, and since 14.04 won’t be finalized until mid-April 2014, will we see a surprise intermediate release of elementary based off of 13.10? elementary OS 0.2.5…?

Answer:

> The devs are using Ubuntu 12.04 as that base, sometime after 14.04 LTS is released “Isis” will be released with 14.04 as the new base

Also (from *elementaryos.org/answers/which-ubuntu-version-is-elementary-os-luna-built-on*, which is now a broken link):

> It is based off Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So far all elementary versions are based of the Ubuntu LTS versions.

So this system will be going from LTS to LTS and not have releases in between.

Comment: @Rinzwind First link is death.

Comment: @empedokles sure is :( relevant part is in the topic though :D Ill try to find it again. 1 sec.